# Apache .htaccess misconfiguration duplicate logfiles

Tags: php, apache

I'm learning some concepts of PHP 8.2.0.(wamp server on windows 11) and I'm trying to learn the PHP error handling options. Here it is my code:

```
<?php

$logFile = "../Logs/logFile.txt";

error_reporting(E_ALL);

function dd($var)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($var);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
}

function forceException()
{
    $msg = "Error transformed in Exception";
    echo "Erro forçado a excepção<br>";
    throw new Exception($msg);
}

set_exception_handler(function(Exception $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents("../Logs/logFile.txt", $error, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    echo "Exception written.<br>";
    return true;
});

set_error_handler('forceException');

echo $b;
```

I'm forcing an error by printing an variable $b that is not defined or initialized. The output of this code into the logFile.txt is this:

```
Error transformed in Exception
Error transformed in Exception
```

As you can see the error message is being duplicate. Would some one help me please? I cannot figure out what is wrong. I thank you all in advance.

I already have made some modifications to my code, but the problem seems to persist whatever I do.

After a lot of debugging I have found that the use of `AllowOverride all` directive on the `<Directory ...>` block in `<VirtualHost ...>` definitions on `httpd-vhosts.conf` file, makes the duplication of this log appear. However, if I ommit it or use the `AllowOverride none`, the duplication seems to be solved. However, this last action creates a new problem as consequence: any URL's like `mydomain.local/subdir` are now unacessble.

Since I need to use an `.htaccess` file to build a PHP MVC framework from scratch (for educational purposes), the directive `AllowOverride all` should be present.

This seems to me to be a server misconfiguration: I already have introduced a sleep(10) function before the echo and the records on the logFile seems to be written 10 seconds later. This means that my script is being called twice.

Let me say that I have a SSL Certificate installed on my dev system.

My `.htaccess` is :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Remove the question mark from the request but maintain the query string
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

# Uncomment the following line if your public folder isn't the web server's root
RewriteBase /

# Accept loading from the actual files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#send everything else to the index page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Again, help would be very apreciate if possible. I really dont know much about apache configurations... I recognize... Thank you all.

Comment: please include the code for `printing an variable $b that is not defined or initialized` so that we can check whether it throws two exceptions

Comment: Hello and thank you for your interest in my problem. This is the only code present on index.php. The only php file. The other file is the logFile.txt to register every errors and exceptions.

Comment: I have tested - the issue you mentioned is NOT reproducible. Please visit `https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO27March2023.php` ONCE and then visit `https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/Logs/logFile.txt` and you will see only one line is inserted for **each run** of the php (I intentionally add a timestamp so that you will see the time/date of the log)

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your reply @Ken. In fact if you cannot reproduce the error, I wonder if it would be some sort of my system configuration that may be triggering the two records into the log file?

Comment: Yes, it is likely, but since I do not use Windows OS I cannot give further comments on the the behavior of wamp on Windows 11, I think you may test your script in a linux server and see what happens. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you @Ken. Have a very nice day too! :-)